# Flask API returns either wrong JSON or blank list

Tags: python, flask

I'm having an issue with a Flask app I'm working on, whenever I send a `POST` request from Postman I get a blank list.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
1  @app.route('/twist', methods=['POST'])
2  def twist():
3       try:
4          session = Session(request.json.get('url'), nameserver=NAMESERVER)
5          session.scan()
6          sessions.append(session)
7          sessionUrl = session.status()
8          urlId = sessionUrl['id']
9          for s in sessions:
10              if s.id == urlId:
11                  return jsonify(s.domains()), 201
12              else:
13                  return return jsonify({'message': 'Scan session not found'}), 404
14      except Exception as err:
15         return jsonify({'message': 'Invalid domain name'}), 400
```

If I get rid of line 10 I do get a valid response on the first try, but if I send a second request with other URL I keep getting the same JSON I got on the first request.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/elceef/dnstwist) as my base code, and I'm not using the original API because I need it to work with just one request.

Edit:
If I split the function in two like this:

```
@app.route('/twist', methods=['POST'])
def twist():
    try:
        session = Session(request.json.get('url'), nameserver=NAMESERVER)
        session.scan()
        sessions.append(session)
        sessionUrl = session.status()
        urlId = sessionUrl['id']
        return jsonify(urlId), 201
    except Exception as err:
        return jsonify({'message': 'Invalid domain name'}), 400

@app.route('/twist/<sid>/domains')
def api_domains(sid):
    for s in sessions:
        if s.id == sid:
            return jsonify(s.domains())
    return jsonify({'message': 'Scan session not found'}), 404
```

And I make two separate requests using the `urlId` as the `sid` it works like a charm.

Comment: You want to `return` on the first found session? What happens if no session matches the condition?

Comment: it should return a dictionary with possible variations of a URL
i.e:
URL = google.com should return {'original':'google.com', '1':'go0gle.com', '2':'g0ogle.com', '3':'googl3.com'... and so on}
You can see an online version of this [here](https://dnstwister.report/)

Comment: You did not answer my questions.

Comment: Sorry, `.domains()` generates info based on the sessions stored in `sessions` and it should return the info generated by `.domains()`, if no sessión matches the condition it should `return` `{'message': 'Scan session not found'}, 404`, it seems I forgot to write that line on lines 12 & 13

Comment: Now your code will return in the first iteration in any case. Other sessions in the list will not be considered.

Comment: Exactly, but I know there will only be one session so that's not a problem

Comment: Line 12 miss ":" after else?

Comment: No, it was just a transcript typo but thanks for letting me know hehe